Is there a counterexample to the No-Loop Conjecture when $A$ is not an Artin algebra?
Let $A$ be an Artin algebra, i.e., $A$ is an algebra over a commutative Artin ring $R$ that is a finitely generated $R$-module.
The No-Loop Conjecture states that when $A$ is an Artin algebra (or more generally an Artinian ring), if $A$ has finite global dimension, then
$$
\text{Ext}^1(S, S) = 0
$$
for all simple $A$-modules $S$.
My question is: when $A$ is not an Artin algebra, i.e., $A$ is a general ring, is there a counterexample to the No-Loop Conjecture?

Have you tried $A=\mathbb{Z}$?

Thank you very much! Yes, when we take $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $S = \mathbb{Z}_2$, we obtain a counterexample because $\text{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z}_2) = \mathbb{Z}_2 \neq 0$ and $\text{gldim}(\mathbb{Z}) = 1 < \infty$. Thank you again.
